# Redirect user if value in the redux store is not present from component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

If a value is not present in the redux store, uuser should be redirected to a page and if not, it should continue

As per react lifecycle methods, constructor seems to be the right place for this butt I am not sure, If I should do this here or not. Do we have any other approach to  this.

in constructor(), 
if(id found in redux store), continue else rediect user to a page.

Comment: i would prefer componentWillMount

Comment: It's unsafe to use componentWillMount since it's a legacy API and will be removed in the future release
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 0):

You should handle redirects in the render method. So when your props change your app will be able to react to those changes.

```
render() {
  if (shouldRedirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/some-page"} />
  }
  ...
  Everything else can stay the same here
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the availability first

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      valuePresentIn: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkValueAvailability(myReduxStoreData);
  }
  checkValueAvailability(data) {
  // Condition if the data is available
    if (data) {
      this.setState({ valuePresentIn: true });
    }
  }
  render() {
    this.state.valuePresentIn ?
      redirect()
      :
      null
  }

  return(<yourComponents />);
}
```